# MS Project crashes / quits when opening mpp file or using project

Tags: crash, microsoft-project

I'm trying to use MS Project Professional 2003 (in Win XP SP2 and the lastest updates from the microsoft website have been installed).

When I open a .mpp file - Project quits unexpectedly without an error message. If I double click the mpp file, Project starts up but then immediately quits.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a solution for this problem?**

Repair your MS Project Professional 2003 using the following instructions.

> Reference [How to install or repair and reinstall Office 2003 programs
>   and features](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821593)
>
> **How to repair problems in 2007 Office programs and features that are already installed**
>
> You can use either one of the following methods to detect and to
>   repair problems that are associated with 2007 Office programs and
>   features taht are already installed, For example, incorrect registry
>   settings or missing installation files. You cannot use these methods
>   to repair personal files.
>
> **Method 1: Run the Microsoft Office Diagnostics feature**
>
> To run the Microsoft Office Diagnostics feature from a 2007 Office
>   program, follow these steps:
>
> - Start the Office Diagnostics tool. To do this, use either of the following methods:
>
>   - For a menu-based 2007 Office program, click Office Diagnostics on the Help menu.
>   - For a ribbon-based 2007 Office program, follow these steps:
>
>     - Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Program Options.
>     - Note In this option, Program represents the name of the program.
>     - In the Navigation Pane, click Resource.
>     - Click Diagnose.
> - Click Continue.
> - Click Start Diagnostics.
> - Note If the Office Diagnostics tool identifies a problem, it tries to fix the problem.
> - When the Office Diagnostics tool completes, click Close.
>
> Note You can also run the Microsoft Office Diagnostics feature from
>   the Start menu. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> - In Windows, click Start
> - Point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Office, point to Microsoft Office Tools, and then click Microsoft Office Diagnostics.
>
> **Method 2: Run the Detect and Repair feature**
>
> - Click Start.
> - If you are running Windows Vista or Windows 7, copy and paste (or type) the following command in the Search programs and files box, and
>     then press ENTER:
>
>   - appwiz.cpl
> - If you are running Windows XP, click Run, copy and paste (or type) the following command in the Open box, and then press ENTER:
>
>   - appwiz.cpl
> - Click the name of the Microsoft Office Edition 2007 that you want to change, and then click Change.
> - Click the option Repair, and then click Continue.